# LocalStorage data not showing on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help please. I have the code below in a `table` to show the stored data but it's not showing the information. I know the data are being stored since I can monitor the changes in the resource tab of chrome. Any idea?

```
<p id="lastname"><script>$('#lastname').html(localStorage.getItem('lastname').replace(/"/g,''));</script></p>
```

**EDIT**

By the way, below is the code to save the data. I call this function on every onBlur of the input fields. Like I said above, I see the data being stored via resource.

```
function setValues(name){
    if (name=="civil_status" || name=="sex"){
        localStorage.setObject(name,$('#'+name+'2').val());
    } else {
        localStorage.setObject(name,$('input[name='+name+']').val());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Problem solved! I noticed I was using the same "id" references for the ones in the input fields and those in the tables. Must be from the lack of sleep all night. :)

Comment: Can you take that script outside of the `p` tag? It should not be there. Also if you are in chrome can you go to console and just enter `localStorage.getItem('lastname')` to see what it returns?

Comment: @scrowler that's not a syntax error, it's regex...

Comment: @Adam `localStorage.getItem('lastname')` shows `"dela cruz"` as value, hence the `replace` item in the jquery to remove the quotes.

Comment: Are you running this all on the same domain? Are there any iframes on this page?

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity... What is `localStorage.setObject`? Are you adding a prototype method to the `localStorage` global?

Comment: @Adam Not sure. I found that particular code snippets here as one of the solutions involving writing to `localStorage`.

Edit: Ah yes, I guess I am adding a prototype method after all. I also have the following based on the solutions I found.   `Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}`

Comment: Okay, because `localStorage` is all string based. The spec has no method `setObject` if you wanted to set an object you'd really have to json encode it and then decode it to get the data. Also it's not a good idea to write prototype methods. It's bad for compatibility forwards and backwards.